# Snowflake - Using an IFF clause in an Update

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm attempting to do an update only if a value is not contained in a tertiary table, like this:

```
update FIRST_TABLE t1
set iff(t1.name!=t2.name, t3.new_name, t1.name)
from SECOND_TABLE t2
  , THIRD_TABLE t3
where t1.id=t2.id
  and t1.name=t3.name
```

Note that T1 will be updated in a separate, previous step, so it will contain names from T2 instead of its original T1 names. T3 is there as a catch for names that were not caught initially by T2.

Example:

T1:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex |
| 2 | Mark |
| 3 | Luke |
| 4 | John |

T2:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Xander |
| 2 | Marcus |

T3:

| name | new_name |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | Alexander |
| John | Jonathan |
| Luke | Lucas |

Updated T1:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Xander |
| 2 | Marcus |
| 3 | Lucas |
| 4 | Jonathan |

However I can't seem to use the iff statement here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing to name the column this update is updating.

An equivalent simpler update with the same problem:

```sql
update first_table t1
set iff(1=0, 3, 4);
```

The solution:

```sql
update first_table t1
set a = iff(1=0, 3, 4);
```

Setup:

```sql
create temp table first_table as
select 1 a, 2 b;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure I follow, but what I ended up doing was two independent updates, the second being the one that overwrites and takes priority.

Comment: The problem in the question is on `set iff`. Set what?